# How can I change which commit master points to in git?

Tags: git

In git, I've been making commits onto the master branch, when really I should have been working on a feature branch. I want to change this so that master is back to where it started, and what was on master is now on a new branch. Basically, my commit history looks like this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
          |         |
          |       master
     origin/master
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
        master
          |
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
          |         |
          |       new_branch
     origin/master
```

How can I change where master points?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

1. Stash your uncommitted changes: `git stash`
2. Create a new branch: `git branch new_branch`
3. Reset master to origin/master: `git reset --hard origin/master`
4. Check out the new branch again: `git checkout new_branch`
5. Unstash your changes: `git stash pop`

Stash/unstash is not necessary if your working tree is clean. Just make sure there are no changes in your working tree, because those will be removed when you reset --hard

---

Another possibility (faster, and without the need to stash and reset):

1. Check out a new branch: `git checkout -b new_branch master`
2. Create a 'new' master branch and point it to origin/master's commit: `git branch -f master origin/master`

Comment: Note that the stash is only necessary if you have any uncommitted changes.

Comment: Stash commits? Most likely you meant local changes.

Comment: If your working directory is clean you won't need the `stash` and `unstash` parts. Otherwise perfect: +1

Comment: Awesome! `git reset --hard <commit>` was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: You really should not modify files in `.git/refs/` by hand (for one, any given ref might actually be packed (into the `.git/packed-ref` file) instead of being “loose”). In general, the lowest level command you should use to modify a ref is either *git update-ref* or *git symbolic-ref*. In this particular instance there is no need for mucking with Git internals or even using the previously mentioned Git “plumbing” commands; you can do it with *git branch*: `git branch -f master origin/master`.

Comment: `git branch -f master <commit>` did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: Might want to specify that between `git branch new_branch` and `git reset --hard origin/master` you'd need to checkout the master branch with `git checkout master`.

Comment: @dbliss: only, if you've been on a different branch before. But then, `new_branch` will not point to the old tip of master, thus losing commits.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I was thinking that `git branch new_branch` checked out `new_branch`, as would `git checkout -b new_branch`.  The latter is what I normally use.

Comment: Note that at any given time you can change where master points to by using `git update-ref refs/heads/master ....` .

Answer (score 37):

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard <commit-id-for-master-to-sit-at>
```

for example try this

```
$ mkdir example; cd example
$ git init
$ vi testFile.txt
(now add "test commit 1" to line 1 of file)
$ git add *
$ git commit
(add message "(+) 1st commit" to git commit)
$ vi testFile.txt
(now add "test commit 2" to line 1 of file)
$ git add *
$ git commit
(add message "(+) 2nd commit" to git commit)
$ vi testFile.txt
(now add "test commit 3" to line 1 of file)
$ git add *
$ git commit
(add message "(+) 3rd commit" to git commit)
$ git tag final_head
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

this example shows moving the master to a different commit. Note here that the tag allows us to save the old master, in case :)

Comment: What command would you use to push this change so it is reflected in the remote repository, not just locally?

Comment: @Scampbell Easy! Two copies of the same repo so to synchronize, use "git push" or "git push -f" for forced if needed

Comment: I use aliases: gp='git push' & gpf='git push -f'

Comment: That worked, thanks @J-Dizzle ! I had to force it with -f because my local was behind the remote.

"Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart."

Comment: This alias saves me too: gpa='git pull --all' ❤️

Comment: When your local branch is behind, forcing is very risky! Make sure to ‘gpa’ then first; examining the contents that remote has then before you destroy it (e.g. gpa & tag remote’s tip first!!)

Comment: Great point! In this case, it was a messy repo that wasn't managed properly, so it required some serious changes to get in some semblance of order.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout a new branch where branch `main` is, then delete branch `main`, then create branch `main` anew where `main` was intended to be (e.g., at `origin/main`):

```sh
git checkout -b new_branch_where_main_was
git branch -d main
git branch main origin/main
```

Note that this does not change anything in the working directory: `HEAD` remains unchanged, uncommitted changes remain where they are. No stashing needed, no checkouts needed, no resets needed.

Answer (score 3):

Go to .git/refs/heads/master which has the hash of master and change that to whatever you want. I use gitg to quickly find the hash of master and afterwards to verify that the move was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Note that at any given time you can change where a branch points to by using `git update-ref refs/heads/branch id` , but before you do this, you must give a name to the tip of the tree, otherwise your work will unaccessible. So these two commands may do the job

```
 git update-ref refs/heads/newfeature HEAD
 git update-ref refs/heads/master XXYYY
```

But make sure that you do not have any uncommited changes otherwise all hell will break loose

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch `new_branch` at the current HEAD (assuming HEAD = master), reset master to C and switch to `new_branch` again (speaking in terms of SmartGit).